# Zend addFilter rename single file only

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have an upload form that has two file input's.

I want to rename the files so that each have a unique name. Here is what I have in my Controller

```
 public function mainAction()
    {
        $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer(); 
        $files = $upload->getFileInfo();

        foreach ($files as $file => $info) {
            $upload->addFilter('Rename', uniqid($file.'_').'.csv', $file);
        }

        $upload->receive();
     }
```

Even though I have specified the file as the last paramter in setFilter, it renames both files at the same time so that they end up with the same name.

Comment: Hm, and what if you use `addFilter` instead of that `setFilter`?

Comment: oh sorry I am using addFilter, that was atypo

Comment: Hm, do your calls to `uniqid` actually create 2 different strings? (I see a comment about Cygwin on the manual page)

Comment: I thought about that, but the $file prefix would at least be different, but its the same. (Whatever the value of $file was at the last iteration) It renames both files in the last iteration

Comment: Ah, you're right indeed. Well, notoriously badly documented as it is, is `$file` indeed the value by which `Zend_File_Transfer` thinks you should address the file?

Comment: well, I guess that is the part I'm unsure about, the documentation is very vague! I'm looking here for the answer to that. $file returns the name of the input field, not the actual uploaded file name.

Comment: Just tried giving it the filename of the uploaded files, those didn't work either.

Comment: According to the comments in the code the key _'... is the name within the form or, if not set the filename'_. You could always use a [bit of reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.getvalue.php) to get the value of the protected `->files` property to check the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.

This is the form:

```
<input type="file" name="one">
<input type="file" name="two">
```

this goes in the controller

```
       $renamefile1 = new Zend_Filter_File_Rename(array(
         'target'    => $path.'/file1.csv', // path to file
         'overwrite' => true
        ));

       //rename file 2 to file2
       $renamefile2 = new Zend_Filter_File_Rename(array(
         'target'    => $path.'/file2.csv', // path to file
         'overwrite' => true
        ));


       $names = $upload->getfileName();
       $file1 = $renamefile1->filter($names["one"]);
       $file2 = $renamefile2->filter($names["two"]);
```